# how to bind click event to checkbox label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping a javascript / jquery guru can help me out.

I'm trying to figure out a way to launch a popup box (fancybox) from the click of a checkbox label. I don't want to effect the checkbox function which filters data when clicked.

I would welcome any thoughts on how I can make this happen. I've tried an onclick function on the label but that doesn't work.

I want to show a fancybox when you click on a persons name in the checkbox label. Here's the site:- (example: jonathanlyon)

http://monkeygetnews.jonathanlyon.com/bs.php

The checkboxes are built dynamically and I need to create a click event on the label that opens a fancybox. Here's the code to build the checkboxes:-

```
<input type="checkbox" id = "dn" value="dept_<?php echo $currdept;?>" onchange="doSearch();return false;" />
<label><?php echo $currdept;?></label>
<ul class="dept_<?php echo $currdept;?>">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name = "un" value="<?php echo $usernames;?>" <?php echo $include;?> onchange="doSearch();return false;" />
        <label><?php echo $usernames;?></label>
    </li>   
<?php
$dept = $currdept;
} else {
?>                
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name = "un" value="<?php echo $usernames;?>" <?php echo $include;?> onchange="doSearch();return false;" />
    <label><?php echo $usernames;?></label>
    </li>
<?php
$dept = $currdept;

}
?>
```

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Please post a small code excerpt here, not a link to a huge web page with unrelated content.

Comment: sorry - see amended question

Comment: Don't attach the label to the input by wrapping or using `for`, and just attach a click event to the label, like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjXpK/)

Comment: See the documentation on [*jQuery mouse events*](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) to understand how you can bind an action to the click event of the `label` element.

Comment: Where's the `onclick` that you said you tried?

Comment: I removed it as it didn't work

Comment: @adeneo that worked (almost ;-)) however it only works on the first name - dasfaha) try it out and hopefully you'll see what I mean

Comment: How am I supposed to try out your server generated PHP code? You did of course not use the same ID twice!

Comment: umm I did, is that wrong? How could I do it with unique id's? Sorry I know it's frustrating dealing with a newbie

Comment: You need to use classes instead, like [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AjXpK/1/) ...

Comment: @adreno can you add it as an answer so I can accept it please

Answer (score 1):

Very simply put you can use jquery like this

```
$('label').click(function() {
    alert($(this).html());
}
```

again, this is a very simple example and would need improvement

Comment: @JonathanLyon This will work in your code because clicking the label is not triggering a checkbox toggle currently

Comment: You can place it anywhere really.  If you have a javascript file with all your javascript code place it in there.  You may need to to wrap it in $(document).ready to ensure the dom is loaded

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap checkbox tag with label tag to make label clickable like

`<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value"/>dasfaha</label>`

**Edit:**

Sorry guys. I didn't look carefully. Here is how to detect label or checkbox.
How it works is that when you click unbounded label, checkbox won't be changed. However, when you click checkbox, ':checked' will be changed. Thus, you can put a variable to store previous value of checked, then compare with current checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xtyah/

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP wants since clicking the label will toggle the checkbox